# autoreleased objects freed, still running out of memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

http://i46.tinypic.com/2nquzag.png

I have an app that creates and releases millions of NSNumbers during the course of a very long calculation.  I'm using @autoreleasepools with the various loops that create and process these  objects. As you can see by the instruments screen cap, I have only 10656 living CFNumbers, yet at this point the app crashes due to unable to allocate memory for further objects. There are over 57 million CFNumbers in "transitory" state. Does this mean they are released? Why doesn't malloc use these memory locations yet?

I've included a mockup of the code I'm using. Run the testProbabilities method and it will count every 10000 iterations. I'm getting up to 790000 iterations with this code before an alloc error. Yet Instruments looks good to me.

```
@implementation MMTest

NSMutableSet *predictedSet;


-(NSMutableArray *)calculateCDF {

//// NORMALIZE PROBABILITIES ////

float probabilitySum = 0;
float runningCDFTotal = 0;
float normaledProbability = 0;

@autoreleasepool {

    NSMutableArray *CDF = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    probabilitySum = 4.5; ////This is just a placholder for additive iteration of an array which creates this sum.

    //// CREATE CDF ////

    int x;

    for (x=0; x<50; x++) {

        normaledProbability = .2/probabilitySum;////This is placeholder for calculation on same array as above.
        runningCDFTotal += normaledProbability;

        [CDF addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:runningCDFTotal]];

    }

    return CDF;

}

}

-(NSMutableSet *)generateNumbers {

@autoreleasepool {

    int x;
    double r = 0;

    if (!predictedSet) {
        predictedSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }

    else {
        [predictedSet removeAllObjects];
    }

    for (x=0; x<5;) {

        r = arc4random_uniform(1000)/1000;////I'm actually using SFMT here instead.
        int num = 0;
        __weak id CDF = [self calculateCDF];


        if (r <= [[CDF objectAtIndex:[CDF count]-1] floatValue]) {

            for (NSNumber *cdf in CDF) {

                if (r <= [cdf floatValue]) {

                    num = [CDF indexOfObject:cdf]+1;

                    [predictedSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num]];

                    x++;

                    break;


                }

            }

        }

    }

    return predictedSet;

}

}

-(void)testProbability {

int x = 0;
BOOL nextSetFound = NO;
NSSet *nextSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                  nil];

while (nextSetFound == NO) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        __weak id newSet = [self generateNumbers];

        x++;

        if ([nextSet isSubsetOfSet:newSet]) {

            nextSetFound = YES;
            NSLog(@"%@", newSet);

        }   

        if (fmod (x,10000) == 0) {
            NSLog(@"%i", x);

        }

    }

}

NSLog(@"%i", x);

}

@end
```

Comment: #Transitory is simply the difference between #Overall and #Living. It's not an indication of a problem.

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference then between a completely dealloced object and a transitory one?

Comment: There's no difference. The allocations counted in the #Transitory column have been completely deallocated. "transitory" is not a state of an allocation. It's simply the number of objects that have been deallocated. It tells something about the load on the memory manager but nothing about the current or past memory consumption.

Comment: there's a 1/1000000 chance `NSNumber` is a *better* solution than c's builtin types here…

Comment: Thank you Codo for the clarification. @Justin: I need to add them to arrays and compare the contents to other arrays. So NSNumbers are much easier to work with this way.

Comment: If I reuse the array instance CDF each iteration by issuing removeAllObjects, and populating it again, I can get up to 920000 iterations before crashing. I will try reusing the NSNumber objects next. There should be an easier way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly why, but this exact code above is now working fine as is. In the course of testing various modifications, I enabled and disabled Guard Malloc and Malloc Stack Logging in Xcode. All of a sudden my modified versions began running with no crashes. I then tried this original version again and now it runs fine without crashing. It makes no sense, but I am just glad it is working.

@sergio: I would like to upvote your answer at least for providing much help and advice to optimize this code further, but I don't have a high enough reputation. Thank you for your help. I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong or you are not releasing anywhere `CDF`? This way, you are leaking `CDF` each time you call `calculateCDF`.

Try this:

```
id CDF = [self calculateCDF];
```

instead of

```
 __weak id CDF = [self calculateCDF];
```

and

```
id newSet = [self generateNumbers];
```

instead of

```
__weak id newSet = [self generateNumbers];
```

Specifying `weak` will make the object not owned by `newSet` and thus not released automatically by ARC.

On the other hand, Apple [explicitly adives against using `__weak` for stack variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

Take care when using __weak variables on the stack. Consider the following example:

> ```
>        NSString * __weak string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"First Name: %@", [self firstName]];
>        NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
> ```
>
> Although string is used after the initial assignment, there is no other strong reference to the string object at the time of assignment; it is therefore immediately deallocated. The log statement shows that string has a null value. (You will not see the effect if you use, for example, `NSString * __weak string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"First Name"]`. In this case, `initWithString:` simply returns the string constant which is never deallocated.)

As I understand this paragraph, you either have an immediate deallocation, or a memory leak.

I tried your code on an iOS 4.3 iPhone (removing the __weak) and it shows a flat "physical free memory" under instruments.

OLD ANSWER:

The tricky thing with `autorelease` is that autorelease pools are drained at unpredictable times (usually when the app execute the run loop). This is different to using `release` in that it adds some delay between the moment when you are done with an object and the moment when the memory gets freed.

If you multiply this small delay (like an inertia the `autorelease` system has) by the number of autoreleased objects this could lead to peaks of memory usage. If iOS checks memory usage during one of those peaks, and your app cannot react properly to the memory warning that ensues, then you app is killed.

On the other hand, if you allocate a release pool, and it becomes huge within the same step of the run cycle, this could also lead to excessive memory usage.

You provide little detail about your code, so I cannot be more precise; in any case, I would try and explicit `release` objects, if possible. This would get rid of the two issues above. Or you could try and handle smaller autorelease pools (and you would fix the second kind issue)...

I would also suggest you to add a Memory Monitor to Instruments, so you will see how fast the system frees up memory.

PS: Now, what strikes me in the picture you attached is that the allocation diagram is absolutely flat: no allocations, no deallocations. I would expect the memory to go up and down (this is the sign of a healthy iOS app, in my experience).

Comment: I agree that the diagram cannot explain the memory problem at all. There's an overall consumption of 7.5 MB, no peaks, no problem...

Comment: I feel I miss some information: I suspect that your app does positively have a phase when memory allocations goes up (and down when the memory warnings come in); it seems to survive all that and crash when no more allocation of memory is being done. In any case, 7.5 MB of used memory (as reported by the allocation tool) can be enough to have your app killed, it all depends on how much memory the system is left... see also my edit about using the memory monitor tool...

Comment: The image may be misleading. The graph is not zoomed out all the way, so yes there is the initial allocation going up at the beginning. But the app is crashing in the middle of this long calculation that is not finished. The Live bytes stays very even throughout the calculation because of the 3 autorelease pools that are in constant use. I will try the Memory Monitor for further diagnosis.

Comment: http://i47.tinypic.com/b6dh09.png    http://i48.tinypic.com/296myiq.png    Two new screens from a shorter run using the Memory Monitor. It appears that Instruments is quickly eating up all the free memory, and that my app has a relatively unchanged allocation after it gets going. Still does not explain why the app crashes due to allocation errors when Instruments are not running...

Comment: are you sure you are releasing your NSNumber instances? if you store them in a dictionary, they will not be released... could you shown how you create your NSNumbers and what you do with them memory-wise?

Comment: I've attached a mockup of the code. It exhibits the same issues I have with my actual code. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: @sergio  I've tried what you suggested and have the same results. If I test for the existence of CDF at the beginning of calculateCDF I always get false. So it is being released, but it's memory footprint is never reused? I am using ARC btw, so I can't call autorelease commands directly.

Comment: I had missed another `weak` declaration, would you mind have a look at my edit? Also provided some reference... and you are right about autorelease, it is not necessary...

Comment: It seems the physical memory reduction is caused by tracking all allocations in Instruments. If I enable only track active allocs, or don't run allocations at all, the physical memory stays relatively flat. Still can't figure why the app is unable to alloc at a certain point. After some tweaks, including removing the __weak specifiers, and reusing the CDF object and emptying it each time, the app can stay alive for 920000 iterations now. Could it be due to running this method in a detached thread? How many iterations were you able to complete before it crashes?

Comment: I did not let the app run for a long time, just 1 or 2 minutes to see if things got stable...